# Page-title count doesn't update after load

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav, live-refresh

When new questions load via life-refresh, not only does a grey box tell you how many new questions are available to load, the page title also is updated with the count; you'll see `(1)` in your tabs if there is one new question to load, for example.

Unfortunately, actually loading the questions (either by clicking on the grey box, or by using the <kbd>F</kbd> keyboard shortcut if you have that enabled) doesn't reset the title.

Could this be fixed please? I now keep thinking there are more questions to look at when there are none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix for that is rolling out in the next build (build rev `2015.10.27.3789` on MSE/MSO, `2015.10.27.2908` on sites).

Comment: yup, fix rolling out shortly

Comment: Check, looks great again.