# Linked questions section disappeared from sidebar

Tags: bug, linked-questions

For some reason, the Linked Questions section did not properly associate a post with its duplicate.  [This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308991/new-questions-indicator-in-browser-tab-doesnt-disappear) was closed as [duplicate of this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308888/page-title-count-doesnt-update-after-load) by a moderator.  That probably made the auto-comment irrelevant and never posted, but the questions aren't associated with each other in the Linked Questions section.

Is this the intended behavior or just a new-nav bug?  Screenshots below:

Duplicate:

> [image: Duplicate]

Target:

> [image: Target]

Comment: Actually, after a question is asked, it always takes a few minutes for the Related/Linked questions to show up. When I checked just now, it was there, on both questions. I feel like this was brought up before, but I'll need to find it. Either way, not caused by new-nav, it's always been a thing.

Comment: Found [the question I was thinking of](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270894/where-have-all-the-related-questions-links-gone) though it only covers the "Related" section- Might just be a case of caching. (Which would explain why it's there now.)

Comment: @Kendra close enough.  Thanks.

Comment: only question lists are subject of [tag:new-nav]